# .m2 folder is invisible through IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, macos-mojave

I can see .m2 folder in my system, but when browsing through IntelliJ to provide a library path , I cannot see .m2 folder there.

Tried putting the folder path in IntelliJ but it does not have such an option.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you really have a Maven project in IntelliJ.

1. Right-click on your project and select Add Framework Support
2. In the dialog select Maven
3. Then press OK

Comment: Hey, it is not a maven project, I was just using the repository for few JAR file  which have already been downloaded . Now I have copied them and saved them somewhere else to use for Library location. Still issue remains same ,I cannot see .m2 folder from IntelliJ

Comment: Do you have M2_REPO defined in user environment variables related to Maven?

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be `ln -s /path/to/your/home/.m2 /path/to/your/destination`.

I recently get the same question with you, but after search the web I don't find anything that can make the folder visible.So the only way to make it is creating a symbolic link pointing to the directory, which doesn't take up extra space in disk but can use the jars downloaded already.