# Hidden directory Not Shown when Adding Library in IDEA

Tags: jar

Notice I don't use build tools like maven or Gradle.

I just want to add a library in IDEA's Project Structure(`cmd + ;`), [using the java button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRtBq.png). But after it opens my finder, i can't find the hidden directories on my Mac, so I can't select the jar from the {$USER_HOME}/.m2 directory which I've downloaded using maven. Only solution I use is to copy the jar to certain directory and then create the library. So question is as below:

1. How can I make it show the hidden directories when clicking any `+ button` in IDEA?

I have searched the web and find one similar question but not resolved I think, [.m2 folder is invisible through IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854316/m2-folder-is-invisible-through-intellij).

1. Make it show the hidden directories when clicking any + button in IDEA.
2. Search the Web.

Comment: I‘ve provide a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77690321/22733232).